# Can I use different promise implementations together?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written [a script](https://github.com/Cardshifter/HTML-Client/blob/deploy-script/scripts/deploy.js) to deploy a web project. It fist uploads a bunch of files via FTP and then sends a request to a [chat bot](https://github.com/Zomis/Duga) posting a message to https://chat.stackexchange.com/.

I'm new to JavaScript and Node.js, and didn't know about promises when I first wrote the code. I'm now in the process of converting it from using nested callbacks to promises with the Node build-in `Promise`.

For making the HTTP request to the bot I've been using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). There's another library called [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) using Bluebird promises. Are these compatible with the built-in promise implementation? Are there any gotchas I have to look out for?

There's a site listing [Conformant Promise/A+ Implementations](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations), but neither Node.js nor Chromium is listed there. Does this mean that I can't use them together?

Comment: Yes, the new native ES6 promises are Promises/A+ compliant as well. [Maybe we should](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/211) list them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to trust the claim that [Request-promise is a drop-in replacement for Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#request-promise-is-a-drop-in-replacement-for-request)

`bluebird` is a superset of the current built in `Promise` implementation in node. That is to say that you can use them interchangeably except that `bluebird` has more features/methods. Rather than try to mix them I would just use `bluebird` everywhere.

If you really don't want to, though, it shouldn't make any difference in terms of chaining promises together.  The following still logs `hello` as expected.

```
let bluebird = require("bluebird");

new bluebird(resolver => resolver())
.then(() => new Promise(resolver => resolver()))
.then(() => console.log("hello"));
```

Using `Promise = require("bluebird")` is pretty common as well.

Answer (score 1):

They are compatible. Probably some implementations differ a little bit, but the main Promise flow is the same. Bluebird seems to be faster even than the native Node.JS implementation.